# How do you build and include the Facebook Android SDK as per the following instructions

Tags: git, github, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new to github and presume I am missing something in the instructions featured below.

https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect

> First run git submodule update --init to initialize and pull down the
>   version of the Android Facebook SDK that works with this plugin; it
>   will end up under lib/. Copy the src and res folders from
>   lib/facebook-android-sdk/facebook/ into the root of your Cordova
>   Android application. It should merge with the existing src and res
>   folders and not overwrite.

I have been able to successfully run and clone the code for the plugin with `git clone https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect.git`, however the next step doesn't make any sense to me in that I should just run `git submodule update --init`, it seems to me that some type of context is missing. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Wow it was so simple, I simply had to cd to the repo and run the command.